# NRPAD and FPAD padding schemes (Korean Seed?)

Tags: block-cipher, cbc, padding, cbc-mac

I've got an API spec that specifies NRPAD and FPAD as possible padding schemes. I see these being used together with the [Korean SEED algorithm](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4269). The SEED specification however is void of any padding mode description as is the API.

Can anybody tell where these padding schemes are defined, and how they operate?

Comment: SEED is just a block cipher, and as such does not specify any padding scheme, as it can be used with anything compatible. I have a feeling NRPAD and FPAD are just generic terms for "padding n bits to the right" and "fixed padding"

Comment: @RichieFrame Yeah, I am aware of that, it's just that I cannot find anything. There is SEED for CMS, but that seems to specify PKCS#7 compatible padding. Possibly they are required in some Korean specific scheme...

Comment: Reminder to myself: don't post question about algorithms/protocols that are just *too* obscure/useless :(